# Auto-Refresh sets the "asked at" timestamp to 12 hours

Tags: bug, status-completed, timestamps

When a page is auto refreshed, or it updates itself on Stack Overflow, the shown time is wrong. It always shows "12 hours ago," instead of actual time. If I refresh the page manually, it shows the time correctly, as you can see in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot of this page]

I am using Google Chrome running on Windows 7.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the same kind of issue for Flag Summary Page. I will post quest, once i will allow to post the question. I am using Google Chrome Version 12.0.742.112

Comment: I'm not seeing this. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Browser: `Google Chrome` OS: `Windows 7`

Comment: Something about this post makes me feel rather dizzy...

Comment: Would have +1 if not for confusion caused by screenshot. A border around the image would help. Better still, free-hand borders! (yes, I'm that petty)

Comment: @Lix, I know, those are not freehand circles..or is that not what you're referring to? ;)

Comment: @bar - Hehe - you take me for someone with a FHRC fetish?  That might be true - but it's not what I was talking about :P

Comment: There. Borders! And your +1. (Took me a while to realise I was clicking on the `edit` link in the screenshot and not the actual link!!)

Comment: @Knvn what about other live refresh features like new comments, edits and new answers? Do they work? Also check the Chrome Console for possible errors maybe there is some error and 12 is the default for some odd reason..

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - New comments: _displays fine(you can see on the 2nd screenshot)_ Edit: _Same issue_ New answers: _Same issue_ Console _is not showing any errors_. If I keep the page open for longer time without refreshing it, then the shown time will increase(as 13h, 14h and so on).

Comment: On [StackOverflow home page](http://stackoverflow.com/) the time is incremental(ascending order) i.e. first few posts shows _12h ago_, next few post shows _13h ago_ and so on.

Comment: Weird. Do you have any Chrome Extensions installed? Can you try and disable them for sake of debugging this?

Comment: Disabled all the extensions but still the issue exists. The console shows no errors other than the warning `Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined`. The chrome version is: `17.0.963.2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Update:* the differential (if any) of your clock vs. server time is now taken into account when the page loads.  This is used when calculating and updating relative times in JavaScript.

---

Check the clock on your computer - my guess is that you've mixed up AM / PM.  The auto refresh happens client side and does depend on having a somewhat in sync clock.

Comment: Would it be feasible to factor in the server-client time offset that `StackExchange.init()` calculates internally when updating the timestamps? Apparently I'm something like six seconds off the server, though there's only a small window in which that's visibly relevant.

Comment: yes this was my clock setting issue. That should be `UTC+05:30` but it was set to something else. Now the SO time shows properly.