# Why can't my friend ask questions with a new account

Tags: support, asking-questions, new-users

One of my friends recently created a fresh account (she never used Stack Overflow before and it is me who recommended it to her). Account creation was successful.

However, when she tried to ask a question, Stack Overflow just forwarded her to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

She clicked `proceed`, then Stack Overflow reloaded but still showed this page. She clicked `proceed` again, but the same thing happened. She escape this page. In this page, the `Ask Question` button was disabled.

It's not a question ban or something like that, I guess it is a bug or a new restriction to fresh users?

Comment: @yan - those spaces were there to center the image :P

Comment: @Lix Oops! (neat trick)...

Answer (score 23):

Just a **wild** guess -

did your friend happen to forget to tick the checkbox?

If you do **not** agree to `"...keep these tips in mind when asking."` then you should read them again and again <sub>and again <sub>and again <sub>and again <sub>and again <sub>and again <sub>and again</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>  until you understand and agree with them.  ;)

But in all seriousness, that is the *expected behavior* if you don't agree to keep these tips in mind when asking;  Clicking proceed will simply reload the page.

---

You can test this out yourself simply by opening a private browsing window and trying to ask a question without logging in.

- Chrome - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
- FireFox - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: Nice Border +1 for it, gnat idea @Lix

Comment: lol yeah she forgot. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I like this new meme of wrapping inline images in `<pre>` tags. That's totally not what `<pre>` tags are for.

Comment: @the - If you want to call it a meme that's fine with me; For me it's simply the easiest way to create some sort of border around screen shots with a white background.

Comment: Why do they need a border?

Comment: That way its easier to see the boundaries of the image - If you look at the 3rd & 4th revisions to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132710/auto-refresh-sets-the-asked-at-timestamp-to-12-hours) you'll see that it can sometimes get quite confusing.  You say that the `<pre>` element was not designed for this use but I believe it **is**. Its a block of `"Pre-formatted text"`.  That's basically all I'm using it for - to pre-format the image container and utilize the grey borders.. The happy accident is that I can now also center the image...

Comment: I agree with @TheEstablishment, above all: I find editing *other* people's posts to add one's own liking quite annoying (just like when adding `<kbd>`). Also, if we want images truly centered, then the team could do that using CSS. One day they might do so (they already do it on the mobile site) and then what would the space "centered" images look like? Currently the spaces already add extra whitespace *above* the image on the mobile theme. (I wonder what a screen reader makes out of it, but I guess they just ignore it. An empty `alt` text might help, but that's another issue.)

Comment: @arj - Yes, I agree with your general idea. If the **only edit** you make is to adhere to a personal preference and posting style then that could *definitely* get annoying.  I can also see how those extra spaces are kind-of unless on the mobile view - they don't break anything but become meaningless because of the change in width of the page.  The main reason that I do this is when I see a screen shot with a white border that conflicts with the post's white background...  I don't think they should implement automatic centering though... You don't always want the image to be centered...